# How to alert and stop attempted segue if video is recording

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a view that allows video recording via a start/stop button without a preview view, and I want to remind the user to stop recording if they attempt to change storyboard views (by touch gesture or by a flipside info button) while a video is recording. How can I prevent the segue to another view if an AVFoundation video capture session is active, and make a `UIAlertView` pop up that reminds the user to stop recording first. I put the UIAlertView in a `viewWillDisappear` and it pops up but I don't know how to make the popup conditional, or to stop the segue from proceeding. Thank you for any assistance and example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Disable the button/gesture.
2. Instead of creating the segue from the button/gesture in IB, create it from the view controller. Then you can have the button/gesture's action method call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` following whatever validation logic you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the button/gesture or whatever that allows the view to be changed. (Make a visual change to it so that the user know that it is disabled). Or you can add a new handler for the button/gesture to display the alert.